# how to detect water with google maps api?

Tags: google-maps

I have coordinate (lat, lon) and my question is - can we detect water under with google maps api?

And can we find nearest apartment with this api if possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Verify if a point is Land or Water in Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644452/verify-if-a-point-is-land-or-water-in-google-maps)

Comment: I put together an open source version of https://IsItWater.com that can be self hosted https://github.com/dillonstreator/is-on-water. I also created a quick-deploy template on railway.app https://railway.app/template/MfUYQX?referralCode=ToZEjF.

Answer (score 0):

With Google *reverse geocoding* you can find the nearest location. If there are zero results, you probably are in an inhabited area.

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps API won't tell you if a location is pointing to water, unfortunately.

Also, since it's Places API doesn't track apartments, it can't show you the closest apartment.